# Coding with c: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exp10’

Tags: c, compilation, warnings

//SOLVED HERE: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962252/coding-with-c-warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function

I don't understand how to compile this.

I've didnt put all of the functions that i've made in this library because all of them work properly, and it's the first time that i have to use math.h

Until now i've compiled like this without issues:

```
gcc -c -g f.c

gcc -c -g main.c

gcc -o main main.o f.o
```

I've tried to insert `-lm` but i don't get how and where it has to be putted.

//header

```
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} bool;

typedef enum {ERROR=-1, OK=1} status;

status parse_int(char s[], int *val);
```

//function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"f.h"


status parse_int(char s[], int *val) {

    int l, val_convertito = 0, val_momentaneo = 0;
    for(l = 0; s[l] != '\0'; l++);
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            val_momentaneo = ((int) (s[i]-48)) * ((int)exp10((double)l--)); 
            val_convertito += val_momentaneo;
            *val = val_convertito;
        } else return ERROR;
    }

    return OK;
}
```

//main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"f.h"


int main() {

    int val_con, *val, ls;
    char s_int[ls];

    printf("Inserisci la lunghezza della stringa: ");
    scanf("%d", &ls);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Inserisci l'intero da convertire: \n");
    scanf("%s", s_int);

    val = &val_con;

    status F8 = parse_int(s_int, val);

    switch(F8) {
        case OK:  printf("Valore convertito %d\n", val_con);
                  break;
        case ERROR: printf("E' presente un carattere non numerico.\n");
                    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding `-lm` to your `gcc` command

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've done It but i dont understand where ti put it

Comment: `gcc -o main -lm main.o f.o`

Comment: The error have nothing to do with linking. There is no standard `exp10`, so therefore it must be an extension of GCC, and you have to search [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) to find out which header it is declared in, if any, and include that header file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is a GNU extension indeed. But an extension of the `math` library. So it has to be linked with `-lm` anyway. Also it looks like `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is needed. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exp10.3.html

Comment: horrible algorithm anyway. using exp for such a simple task

Comment: @PeterJ_01 instead of just making a critic you could say how you would do It otherwise your comment it's useless lol

Comment: @Zeno Raiser lol? Learn a bit first. One of the worst algorithms I've seen here - but for you - read and learn (very simple version) `int char_to_int(const char* value)
{
 int res = 0;
 while (*value)
 {
  if (!isdigit(*value)) return -1;
  res *= 10;
  res += *value++ - '0';

 }
 return res;
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. You do need any exp10 and double values for this task.
2. You have standard C functions like strlen to discover the string length (but is not needed here

Your function can be stripped down to the :

```
int str_to_int(const char* value)
{
    int res = 0;
    while (*value)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*value)) return -1;
        res *= 10;
        res += *value++ - '0';

    }
    return res;
}

status str_to_int1(const char* value, int *res)
{
    *res = 0;
    while (*value)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*value)) return ERROR;
        *res *= 10;
        *res += *value++ - '0';

    }
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i need

Comment: @Zeno Raiser easy to amend  to your typedefs - see the second one

Comment: Thanks man really but i need to learn how ti compile with math.h, that's the point of my question

Comment: you do not need math here. math is for floating point computations - you only do the integer ones. Using math for this task is the wrong practice, and if it a homework - should not be accepted.

Comment: I understand what are you saying, but i want to learn how ti compile with math.h, it's not a fact if It is needed or not

Comment: So use any other function instead of exp10 which is not standard.

Comment: this is what i needed https://askubuntu.com/questions/962252/coding-with-c-warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function

Answer (score 0):

`pow(10.0, x)` does what `exp10(x)` does.